# Deployment Error: Product2 - Custom Object - You can’t change the org-wide sharing defaults for products

Tags: deployment-error

I am receiving the below error message when deploying a build to a sandbox. We don't use Product2 object at all. Never have. No idea why it is complaining? Any recent changes would have nothing to do with Product2 object. Can someone please shed some light on this error message? I looked at [this](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.admin_sharing.htm&type=5), but no luck. Thanks!

[image: Deployment Error]

Comment: How are you deploying? tools, version and package.xml would help

Comment: winter 22 added support for OWD for Product2. Are you deploying from a winter 22 sandbox to a non-winter 22 org?

Answer (score 1):

the issue is described in Known Issues: https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000002BjyrQAC

workaround provided:

> Remove the  tag from the Product2.object file in the package

Answer (score 0):

Is this an org that you haven't deployed to before? You can either try changing the sharing settings for product2 in your org to conform to what's specified in product2.object of your package or remove the sharing settings from that object in your package.